# How can i delete folder with unicode name in python 2.7, window 7

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, I can delete folder with a Ascii name. 
I use:
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('folder_name')
But when folder name contains unicode character, like "今年将不再", i receive error:The system cannot find the path specified.
Is there solution to delete folder in this case.
Thank!

Comment: "it can not work!" is not very informative. Add to your question [a complete minimal code example](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) that shows the problem along with any errors that you get.

Comment: i know shutil.rmtree('/folder_name') can remove folder. But with folder name which has unicode character, i receive exception:The system cannot find the path specified.Can you give me solution? Thank

Comment: read the link. In particular the part "Sample code and data". Then [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16206474/edit), don't put relevant info in the comments.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem.  Shutil.rmtree fails with an error if there exists a file inside the tree with a unicode filename.  Guess I'll write a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Use Unicode strings.  Make sure to specify the encoding of the source file and that you actually save the source file in that encoding if you specify non-ASCII characters in strings:

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
os.remove(u'美国人.txt')
os.rmdir(u'马克')
```

If you read a directory of files programmatically via commands like `os.listdir` or `os.walk`, use Unicode to specify the directory or you won't get Unicode filenames:

```
>>> os.listdir('.')
['???.txt', '??']
```

vs.

```
>>> os.listdir(u'.')
[u'\u7f8e\u56fd\u4eba.txt', u'\u9a6c\u514b'] # Unicode escapes are 美国人and 马克.
```